# Backbone.js: How do I identify the model of the parent view upon an event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have two collections instantiated: items and sections.

Each section can have multiple items and each item can occur in more than one section.

When I add an item to a section I want to get the hash of that item and save it to an array attribute of the section. This array attribute is used to determine which items are displayed in each section.

So let's say that I have a ItemListModel with 100 items and I have a section with an 'items' attribute with the array [ item3_id_hash, item27_id_hash, item59_id_hash ]. When I display the SectionView, I first map those hash ids to the Items collection to get those objects and then I create an ItemsView that displays only those objects.

The problem I have is in identifying those Items upon creation and upon deletion so that I can get their ids and add/remove them from the section.item attribute array.

I can think of a hackish solution to identify the item upon addition by setting a global variable called parent. I want to avoid using globals however.

Removing is another matter entirely. When the user clicks the X to delete an item in the view, I can't figure out how I can either identify the parent Section's model, or at the very least identify its ID.

Example view:

- Section_1

  - Item_1
  - Item_2
  - Item_3
- Section_2

  - Item_4
  - Item_5
  - Item_6

If the user deletes Item_2 from the view, how can I get Section_1.model.get('id') so I can get the section_1 object and then remove the 'id' for Item_2 from the 'items' array attribute in Section_1

The only solution I can think of is passing the 'id' for Section_1 to the HTML view when I draw ItemsView for Section_1. This is hackish and fragile so I was trying to avoid it.

FYI: SectionListView instantiates one or more SectionsViews, each of which instantiate one ItemListView, which instantiates one or more ItemViews

Answer (score 1):

You should always go back to the model. If you want to remove an item, then remove it from the model list and have the different view listen for the removal events.

So your section is observing the List remove event and act accordingly (either remove the element on the page or re-render it self completely).

Models and events (alternatively, routes) should be preferred to glue code in most situation.

I hope I understood your question.

Comment: Given my very specific use case I don't see how I can go back to the model within the sections. Basically what I am trying to create is the equivalent of "symbolic links". I only want the section to save symbolic links to the items added to it. I don't want the sections to contain the items themselves as the same item can exist in more than one section. How do I save references to an Item's model in an individual Section model?

Comment: I'm setting it up "relationally" where the Section saves the foreign keys of the item's added to it. Is it possible for a section to save a references to individual item models instead of item foreign keys? If so, how?

Comment: You said "If you want to remove an item, then remove it from the model list". Is it possible to have each section save it's own Item model list which are subsets of the entire list of item models? i.e. I have a Global.ItemsList collection contains all 100 items. Each section has their own ItemsList collection, which are subsets of those 100 items. Items can appear in more than one Section.ItemsList.

Comment: You can create as many ItemModelList as you want. Each Item can be found in 1 or many of them. There are no restrictions there. You can also create a model to describe your Section and have an attribute of that section model to contain the list of item. With that in place and your views listening to your models, your views would reflect the current model status.

Comment: I tried that but I was unable to save an instantiation of an ItemsList collection to a section. When the section is created I did: Sections.create({ title: this.title.val(), items: new pg.collections.ItemsList ); .....  However when I go to retrieve 'items' using: this.model.get('items');, I get an empty array instead of a collection